# Function definition does not declare parameters error in a template

Tags: c++, template-specialization

The question has been asked before, but not in the same context.

Code:

```
    namespace std
    {
    template <typename T, typename U>
    struct hash < pair <T,U> >
    {
        size_t operator()
        {
            return hash<T>()(first) ^ hash<U>()(second);
        }
    };
    }
```

I am trying to use unordered_map because the elements do not need to be sorted. But this requires a hash comparison function. The following code generates a compile time error:

"error: function definition does not declare parameters"

The problem is that my map does not contain only built-in types, but a mixture:

```
typedef std::vector<Point> Point_Set;
typedef std::unordered_map < Point_Set, double > Tree;
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: or `operator()(const pair<T,U>&)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator needs to take a pair as a parameter, and use the `first` and `second` members of that:

```
size_t operator()(pair<T,U> const & pair)
{
    return hash<T>()(pair.first) ^ hash<U>()(pair.second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here that don't look like C++.

- You hash struct has two template arguments but you call it with one.
- The operator() doesn't take any parameters, but you give it one.
- first is not declared anywhere but you use it as a parameter to operator().

Comment: Regarding your first point, it's a partial specialisation of a template with one parameter, for arguments that are specialisations of `std::pair`.